# TypeError with scikit-learn's BallTree

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.6, typeerror, nearest-neighbor

I have this toyexample with scipy's [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) which works very well  and I want to do a similar piece of code with scikit-learn's[BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

min_neighbors = 3
x,y = np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]

 grid_x,grid_y = np.mgrid[1:6,1:6]
 points = np.c_[x.ravel(),y.ravel()]

 grid_points = np.c_[grid_x.ravel(),grid_y.ravel()]
 tree = spatial.cKDTree(points)
 indices = tree.query_ball_point(grid_points,r=1)
 for idx,(matches,grid) in enumerate(zip(indices,grid_points)):
     if len(matches) >= min_neighbors:
         x1,y1 = tree.data[matches].T
```

When I do a similar toy example with BallTree such as the following

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree import BallTree
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

import sys

def main():
    min_neighbors = 3
    x,y = np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]  
    grid_x,grid_y = np.mgrid[1:6,1:6]
    points = np.c_[x.ravel(),y.ravel()]
    grid_points = np.c_[grid_x.ravel(),grid_y.ravel()]
    bt = BallTree(points,leaf_size=1, metric='haversine')
    indices = bt.query_radius(grid_points,1)

    for idx,(matches,grid) in enumerate(zip(indices,grid_points)):
        #print(matches)
        if len(matches) >= min_neighbors:
           x1,y1 = bt.data[matches].T

 main()
```

I get the following error -

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testballtree.py", line 25, in <module>
   main()
   File "testballtree.py", line 23, in main
    x1,y1 = bt.data[matches].T
   File "stringsource", line 406, in      View.MemoryView.memoryview.__getitem__
   File "stringsource", line 746, in View.MemoryView.memview_slice
   TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

What is the exact way to get access to the data attribute in scikit-learn's BallTree in a way that is identical to scipy ?

```
  scikit-learn version is 0.19.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the docs are wrong and `bt.data` is a memory view and not a numpy array. It should probably be a numpy array or be private. You can just fix your snippet by using `points` instead, though. Opened https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11728

Answer (score 1):

`BallTree.data` is [a view or a copy of the training data](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/adddf00433a961dc1186f91d791a11230f38840e/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi#L1064-L1067), so in your example above you could use `points` array directly instead.

The `data` attribute docstring is indeed incorrect: it is a memoryview instead of an an array. You can convert it back to a numpy array with `numpy.asarray(bt.data)`.